# Redirect url with index.php to non index.php AND character underscore to dashes (.htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

In default. Codeigniter url have index.php in every url then using underscore.

My configuration righ now.

in Routes.php I've set `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;` . That's mean when i try to enter example.some_path it will be go to example.some-path

in my congfig.php.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';// remove'index.php';
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# Don't listing directory
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://example/404

# Origin setting
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(.+\.)?example\.com(:\d{1,5})?$" CORS=$0

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{CORS}e" env=CORS
Header merge  Vary "Origin"
```

Issues right now.

1) Yes, example.com or example.com/somepath (without index.php) is working. BUT example.com/index.php or example.com/index.php/somepath also still available and working too. It will be duplicate content error when visitor access it even I've no-index with robots.txt.  So how to maksesure anyting with index.php not accessible? with .htaccess?

2) After set `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;` , all link with underscores automatically  translate to dashes (AND automatically insert index.php once I click link in my site that's contains underscore) .. (ex: once I click link `<a href="http://example.com/some_path">my link</a>` it will translate to example.com/index.php/some-path). When I try visit example.com/some-path directly without click any link form my site. Yes, example.com/some-path working.

How to makesure index.php can't accessible and automatically redirect to non index.php?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using web.config like I do. I'm not much of a fan of .htaccess
Maybe something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> means?